# Regex: Match partial string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need some help - my skills here falls short :) (and I don't know if it is possible with pure regex)

Case: I have some text inputs in the form of:

input1: "**abc,clutter,01**;xyz,clutter,02;" (should match)
input2: "abc,clutter,02;zyz,clutter,01;" (no match)
input3: "abc,clutter,02;**abc,txt,txt,01**;xyz,clutter,01" (should match)

Then match should be

- Starts with abc (anywhere in the input)
- Everything in between - unless ,02; is in-between
- Ends with ,01;

So something like:
`abc(.*)(?!,02;),01;`
.. but this also matches input2, and that was not the intension :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use for example a repeating pattern matching all chars except `,` and `;`

```
\babc(?:,(?!02,)[^,;\n]+)*,01;
```

- `\babc` A word boundary, match abc
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `,(?!02,)[^,;\n]+` Negative lookahead, assert not 02, and match any char except `,` `;` or a newline
- `)*` Close the group and optionally repeat
- `,01;` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oUmisV/1)

If abc should only be matched one, you can also add that to the negative lookahead

```
\babc(?:,(?!(?:02|abc),)[^,;\n]+)*,01;
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U40dIp/1)